# Batch File Ending Prematurely

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch file with the following commands (to set up a compiler):

```
del Yylex.java

jflex scanner.flex

del parser.java

java -jar java-cup-11a.jar parser.cup
```

However, for some reason, after the conclusion of `jflex scanner.flex`, the batch script ends and command prompt closes. If I just run that command separately, this does not happen. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `jflex` a batch file?

If so, try

```
CALL jflex ...
```

or

```
start /wait "" jflex ...
```

(well, actually - give it a whirl anyway, can't hurt...)

When bat is asked to run another batch, it merely transfers control to that other batch and has no idea of where to return. `CALL` or `START` gives it a ticket home...